# logstash Twitter error when geo_enable=true

Tags: twitter, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to connect logstash to twitter.  All the twitter that user.geo_enabled=false parsed ok, but of the other hand if user.geo_enabled=true I receive this error:

```
 Failed action.  {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil,       :_index=>"twitter", :_type=>"logs", :_routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0xb1b69ba @metadata_accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x74b553ef @store={}, @lut={}>, @cancelled=false, @data={"created_at"=>"Wed Jul 06 16:15:26 +0000 2016", "id"=>750724847626493953, "id_str"=>"750724847626493953", "text"=>"@HillaryClinton I would never vote for you", "source"=>"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>", "truncated"=>false, "in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil, "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil, "in_reply_to_user_id"=>1339835893, "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>"1339835893", "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>"HillaryClinton", "user"=>{"id"=>772001468, "id_str"=>"772001468", "name"=>"charles c hutchison", "screen_name"=>"49_mail", "location"=>nil, "url"=>nil, "description"=>nil, "protected"=>false, "verified"=>false, "followers_count"=>8, "friends_count"=>99, "listed_count"=>0, "favourites_count"=>8, "statuses_count"=>176, "created_at"=>"Tue Aug 21 18:22:06 +0000 2012", "utc_offset"=>nil, "time_zone"=>nil, "geo_enabled"=>true, "lang"=>"en", "contributors_enabled"=>false, "is_translator"=>false, "profile_background_color"=>"C0DEED", "profile_background_image_url"=>"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_image_url_https"=>"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_tile"=>false, "profile_link_color"=>"0084B4", "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"C0DEED", "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"DDEEF6", "profile_text_color"=>"333333", "profile_use_background_image"=>true, "profile_image_url"=>"http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png", "profile_image_url_https"=>"https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png", "default_profile"=>true, "default_profile_image"=>true, "following"=>nil, "follow_request_sent"=>nil, "notifications"=>nil}, "geo"=>{"type"=>"Point", "coordinates"=>[#<BigDecimal:6d26d63b,'0.384274583E2',9(12)>, #<BigDecimal:43f314b6,'-0.823958636E2',9(12)>]}, "coordinates"=>{"type"=>"Point", "coordinates"=>[#<BigDecimal:669bf464,'-0.823958636E2',9(12)>, #<BigDecimal:3d160aa5,'0.384274583E2',9(12)>]}, "place"=>{"id"=>"e4197a23034fa912", "url"=>"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/e4197a23034fa912.json", "place_type"=>"city", "name"=>"Huntington", "full_name"=>"Huntington, WV", "country_code"=>"US", "country"=>"United States", "bounding_box"=>{"type"=>"Polygon", "coordinates"=>[[[#<BigDecimal:4feaddd3,'-0.82530433E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:5438cd7c,'0.38375981E2',8(12)>], [#<BigDecimal:413b49ac,'-0.82530433E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:58a6101d,'0.38439347E2',8(12)>], [#<BigDecimal:445e692e,'-0.82349236E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:5f332e20,'0.38439347E2',8(12)>], [#<BigDecimal:46c19531,'-0.82349236E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:71e183de,'0.38375981E2',8(12)>]]]}, "attributes"=>{}}, "contributors"=>nil, "is_quote_status"=>false, "retweet_count"=>0, "favorite_count"=>0, "entities"=>{"hashtags"=>[], "urls"=>[], "user_mentions"=>[{"screen_name"=>"HillaryClinton", "name"=>"Hillary Clinton", "id"=>1339835893, "id_str"=>"1339835893", "indices"=>[0, 15]}], "symbols"=>[]}, "favorited"=>false, "retweeted"=>false, "filter_level"=>"low", "lang"=>"en", "timestamp_ms"=>"1467821726124", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-07-06T16:15:26.000Z"}, @metadata={}, @accessors=#<LogStash::Util::Accessors:0x40cb306f @store={"created_at"=>"Wed Jul 06 16:15:26 +0000 2016", "id"=>750724847626493953, "id_str"=>"750724847626493953", "text"=>"@HillaryClinton I would never vote for you", "source"=>"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>", "truncated"=>false, "in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil, "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil, "in_reply_to_user_id"=>1339835893, "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>"1339835893", "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>"HillaryClinton", "user"=>{"id"=>772001468, "id_str"=>"772001468", "name"=>"charles c hutchison", "screen_name"=>"49_mail", "location"=>nil, "url"=>nil, "description"=>nil, "protected"=>false, "verified"=>false, "followers_count"=>8, "friends_count"=>99, "listed_count"=>0, "favourites_count"=>8, "statuses_count"=>176, "created_at"=>"Tue Aug 21 18:22:06 +0000 2012", "utc_offset"=>nil, "time_zone"=>nil, "geo_enabled"=>true, "lang"=>"en", "contributors_enabled"=>false, "is_translator"=>false, "profile_background_color"=>"C0DEED", "profile_background_image_url"=>"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_image_url_https"=>"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_tile"=>false, "profile_link_color"=>"0084B4", "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"C0DEED", "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"DDEEF6", "profile_text_color"=>"333333", "profile_use_background_image"=>true, "profile_image_url"=>"http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png", "profile_image_url_https"=>"https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png", "default_profile"=>true, "default_profile_image"=>true, "following"=>nil, "follow_request_sent"=>nil, "notifications"=>nil}, "geo"=>{"type"=>"Point", "coordinates"=>[#<BigDecimal:6d26d63b,'0.384274583E2',9(12)>, #<BigDecimal:43f314b6,'-0.823958636E2',9(12)>]}, "coordinates"=>{"type"=>"Point", "coordinates"=>[#<BigDecimal:669bf464,'-0.823958636E2',9(12)>, #<BigDecimal:3d160aa5,'0.384274583E2',9(12)>]}, "place"=>{"id"=>"e4197a23034fa912", "url"=>"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/e4197a23034fa912.json", "place_type"=>"city", "name"=>"Huntington", "full_name"=>"Huntington, WV", "country_code"=>"US", "country"=>"United States", "bounding_box"=>{"type"=>"Polygon", "coordinates"=>[[[#<BigDecimal:4feaddd3,'-0.82530433E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:5438cd7c,'0.38375981E2',8(12)>], [#<BigDecimal:413b49ac,'-0.82530433E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:58a6101d,'0.38439347E2',8(12)>], [#<BigDecimal:445e692e,'-0.82349236E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:5f332e20,'0.38439347E2',8(12)>], [#<BigDecimal:46c19531,'-0.82349236E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:71e183de,'0.38375981E2',8(12)>]]]}, "attributes"=>{}}, "contributors"=>nil, "is_quote_status"=>false, "retweet_count"=>0, "favorite_count"=>0, "entities"=>{"hashtags"=>[], "urls"=>[], "user_mentions"=>[{"screen_name"=>"HillaryClinton", "name"=>"Hillary Clinton", "id"=>1339835893, "id_str"=>"1339835893", "indices"=>[0, 15]}], "symbols"=>[]}, "favorited"=>false, "retweeted"=>false, "filter_level"=>"low", "lang"=>"en", "timestamp_ms"=>"1467821726124", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-07-06T16:15:26.000Z"}, @lut={"in-reply-to"=>[{"created_at"=>"Wed Jul 06 16:15:26 +0000 2016", "id"=>750724847626493953, "id_str"=>"750724847626493953", "text"=>"@HillaryClinton I would never vote for you", "source"=>"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>", "truncated"=>false, "in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil, "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil, "in_reply_to_user_id"=>1339835893, "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>"1339835893", "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>"HillaryClinton", "user"=>{"id"=>772001468, "id_str"=>"772001468", "name"=>"charles c hutchison", "screen_name"=>"49_mail", "location"=>nil, "url"=>nil, "description"=>nil, "protected"=>false, "verified"=>false, "followers_count"=>8, "friends_count"=>99, "listed_count"=>0, "favourites_count"=>8, "statuses_count"=>176, "created_at"=>"Tue Aug 21 18:22:06 +0000 2012", "utc_offset"=>nil, "time_zone"=>nil, "geo_enabled"=>true, "lang"=>"en", "contributors_enabled"=>false, "is_translator"=>false, "profile_background_color"=>"C0DEED", "profile_background_image_url"=>"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_image_url_https"=>"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_tile"=>false, "profile_link_color"=>"0084B4", "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"C0DEED", "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"DDEEF6", "profile_text_color"=>"333333", "profile_use_background_image"=>true, "profile_image_url"=>"http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png", "profile_image_url_https"=>"https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png", "default_profile"=>true, "default_profile_image"=>true, "following"=>nil, "follow_request_sent"=>nil, "notifications"=>nil}, "geo"=>{"type"=>"Point", "coordinates"=>[#<BigDecimal:6d26d63b,'0.384274583E2',9(12)>, #<BigDecimal:43f314b6,'-0.823958636E2',9(12)>]}, "coordinates"=>{"type"=>"Point", "coordinates"=>[#<BigDecimal:669bf464,'-0.823958636E2',9(12)>, #<BigDecimal:3d160aa5,'0.384274583E2',9(12)>]}, "place"=>{"id"=>"e4197a23034fa912", "url"=>"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/e4197a23034fa912.json", "place_type"=>"city", "name"=>"Huntington", "full_name"=>"Huntington, WV", "country_code"=>"US", "country"=>"United States", "bounding_box"=>{"type"=>"Polygon", "coordinates"=>[[[#<BigDecimal:4feaddd3,'-0.82530433E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:5438cd7c,'0.38375981E2',8(12)>], [#<BigDecimal:413b49ac,'-0.82530433E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:58a6101d,'0.38439347E2',8(12)>], [#<BigDecimal:445e692e,'-0.82349236E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:5f332e20,'0.38439347E2',8(12)>], [#<BigDecimal:46c19531,'-0.82349236E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:71e183de,'0.38375981E2',8(12)>]]]}, "attributes"=>{}}, "contributors"=>nil, "is_quote_status"=>false, "retweet_count"=>0, "favorite_count"=>0, "entities"=>{"hashtags"=>[], "urls"=>[], "user_mentions"=>[{"screen_name"=>"HillaryClinton", "name"=>"Hillary Clinton", "id"=>1339835893, "id_str"=>"1339835893", "indices"=>[0, 15]}], "symbols"=>[]}, "favorited"=>false, "retweeted"=>false, "filter_level"=>"low", "lang"=>"en", "timestamp_ms"=>"1467821726124", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-07-06T16:15:26.000Z"}, "in-reply-to"], "type"=>[{"created_at"=>"Wed Jul 06 16:15:26 +0000 2016", "id"=>750724847626493953, "id_str"=>"750724847626493953", "text"=>"@HillaryClinton I would never vote for you", "source"=>"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>", "truncated"=>false, "in_reply_to_status_id"=>nil, "in_reply_to_status_id_str"=>nil, "in_reply_to_user_id"=>1339835893, "in_reply_to_user_id_str"=>"1339835893", "in_reply_to_screen_name"=>"HillaryClinton", "user"=>{"id"=>772001468, "id_str"=>"772001468", "name"=>"charles c hutchison", "screen_name"=>"49_mail", "location"=>nil, "url"=>nil, "description"=>nil, "protected"=>false, "verified"=>false, "followers_count"=>8, "friends_count"=>99, "listed_count"=>0, "favourites_count"=>8, "statuses_count"=>176, "created_at"=>"Tue Aug 21 18:22:06 +0000 2012", "utc_offset"=>nil, "time_zone"=>nil, "geo_enabled"=>true, "lang"=>"en", "contributors_enabled"=>false, "is_translator"=>false, "profile_background_color"=>"C0DEED", "profile_background_image_url"=>"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_image_url_https"=>"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", "profile_background_tile"=>false, "profile_link_color"=>"0084B4", "profile_sidebar_border_color"=>"C0DEED", "profile_sidebar_fill_color"=>"DDEEF6", "profile_text_color"=>"333333", "profile_use_background_image"=>true, "profile_image_url"=>"http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png", "profile_image_url_https"=>"https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png", "default_profile"=>true, "default_profile_image"=>true, "following"=>nil, "follow_request_sent"=>nil, "notifications"=>nil}, "geo"=>{"type"=>"Point", "coordinates"=>[#<BigDecimal:6d26d63b,'0.384274583E2',9(12)>, #<BigDecimal:43f314b6,'-0.823958636E2',9(12)>]}, "coordinates"=>{"type"=>"Point", "coordinates"=>[#<BigDecimal:669bf464,'-0.823958636E2',9(12)>, #<BigDecimal:3d160aa5,'0.384274583E2',9(12)>]}, "place"=>{"id"=>"e4197a23034fa912", "url"=>"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/e4197a23034fa912.json", "place_type"=>"city", "name"=>"Huntington", "full_name"=>"Huntington, WV", "country_code"=>"US", "country"=>"United States", "bounding_box"=>{"type"=>"Polygon", "coordinates"=>[[[#<BigDecimal:4feaddd3,'-0.82530433E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:5438cd7c,'0.38375981E2',8(12)>], [#<BigDecimal:413b49ac,'-0.82530433E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:58a6101d,'0.38439347E2',8(12)>], [#<BigDecimal:445e692e,'-0.82349236E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:5f332e20,'0.38439347E2',8(12)>], [#<BigDecimal:46c19531,'-0.82349236E2',8(12)>, #<BigDecimal:71e183de,'0.38375981E2',8(12)>]]]}, "attributes"=>{}}, "contributors"=>nil, "is_quote_status"=>false, "retweet_count"=>0, "favorite_count"=>0, "entities"=>{"hashtags"=>[], "urls"=>[], "user_mentions"=>[{"screen_name"=>"HillaryClinton", "name"=>"Hillary Clinton", "id"=>1339835893, "id_str"=>"1339835893", "indices"=>[0, 15]}], "symbols"=>[]}, "favorited"=>false, "retweeted"=>false, "filter_level"=>"low", "lang"=>"en", "timestamp_ms"=>"1467821726124", "@version"=>"1", "@timestamp"=>"2016-07-06T16:15:26.000Z"}, "type"]}>>], :response=>{"create"=>{"_index"=>"twitter", "_type"=>"logs", "_id"=>"AVXA_h0IgT1Xitpna0uT", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Mixing up field types: class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.DoubleFieldMapper$DoubleFieldType != class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.BaseGeoPointFieldMapper$GeoPointFieldType on field coordinates.coordinates"}}}}, :level=>:warn}
```

I think that the relevent line is

```
{"create"=>{"_index"=>"twitter", "_type"=>"logs", "_id"=>"AVXA_h0IgT1Xitpna0uT", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Mixing up field types: class org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.DoubleFieldMapper$DoubleFieldType != class 
  org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.geo.BaseGeoPointFieldMapper$GeoPointFieldType on field coordinates.coordinates"}}}}, :level=>:warn}
```

my template is :

```
{
 "template": "twitter",
 "order":    1,
 "settings": {
 "number_of_shards": 1
},
 "mappings": {
  "tweet": {
    "_all": {
      "enabled": false
     },
    "properties": {
       "coordinates": {
        "properties": {
          "coordinates": {
            "type": "geo_point"
         },
         "type": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

What can be the problem??

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the field `coordinates.coordinates` in ES expect a type of data which is not the type received.

A solution would be to modify the template, removing the coordinates type. Then you delete your index and reindex your data. In that case the expected type of `coordinates.coordinates` will be dependent on the data inserted.
That should resolve the problem.